# Question about ideals in a Dedekind domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

[Proof is here](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numberfield/unique.html)

I'm reading this proof that if $R$ is a Dedekind domain with field of fractions $K$ , and $I$ is an ideal, then there is an ideal $J$ such that $IJ$ is principal. Furthermore, given any nonzero $a \in I$ , $J$ can be chosen such that $IJ = (a)$.

Two lemmas are proven first:

> Lemma 1: In a Dedekind domain, every ideal contains the product of prime ideals.

> Lemma 2: If $A$ is a proper ideal, there is a $\gamma \in K - R$ such that $\gamma A \subseteq R$. Furthermore, for any nonzero $a \in A$, $\gamma$ can be chosen to have denominator $a$.

Now, the proof is as follows: Let $a \in I$, and let $J = \{\beta \in R: \beta I \subseteq (a) \}$. The claim is that $IJ = (a)$. Let $A = \frac{1}{a} IJ$, which is an ideal of $R$ by definition of $J$. If $A$ is a proper ideal, then by lemma 2, there is a $\gamma$ such that $\gamma A \subseteq R$.

Since $a \in I, J \subseteq A$ since any $j \in J$ can be written as $\frac{1}{a} * a * j$. Therefore, $\gamma J \subseteq \gamma A \subseteq R$.

The next line is where I don't understand. The proof simply says "This implies $\gamma J \subseteq J$. I don't understand why this is true. In fact, I think this is false. Because for any $j \in J$, that implies $\gamma j \in J$, so $\gamma^2 j \in J$, and so on, we have $\gamma^n j \in J$. This seems to imply that the denominator of elements of $J$ can have arbitrarily large valuations.

Why does $\gamma J \subseteq J$? If this step is false, how can the proof be repaired?

Answer (score 2):

After thinking about it some more, I managed to come up with a solution:

To show that $\gamma J \subseteq J$, let $j \in J$ be arbitrary. The goal is to prove that $\gamma j$ satisfies the definition of $J$, so let $i \in I$ be arbitrary. The goal is now to prove that $\gamma i j \in (a)$.

Since $\gamma A \subseteq R$ , and $A = \frac{1}{a} I J$, we have $\frac{1}{a} i j \in A$ , so $\gamma \frac{1}{a} i j \in R$, say it equals $r$. Then, we have $\gamma i j = ar \in (a)$.

The part about $\gamma^n J \subseteq J$ is because we started with an assumption, that such a $\gamma$ existed, to show it leads to a contradiction, so it's fine if it leads to a false statement.